# Python. Проектирование класса модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода, sqlalchemy

Добрый день. Пишу модели для работы с базой данных на Python, использую `ORM`'ку - SQLAlchemy.

Возник такой вопрос проектирования. Вот к примеру у меня класс `Chairman` - это класс модели из базы данных, а свойство `initials` - это уже свойство объекта, который по сути, к БД не относится. То-есть, возможно, тут надо завести еще один класс и в нем писать все методы/свойства этого объекта и просто пробросить ссылку на класс модели, используя композицию/агрегацию.
Но такая ситуация со свойством походу будет единственная.

Вопрос: правильный ли это подход и есть ли смысл тогда заводить отдельный класс в моем случае?

```
class Chairman(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "chairmen"

    id = db.Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    patronymic = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    @property
    def initials(self):
        return "%s.%s.%s%s" % (self.name[0].upper(), self.patronymic[0].upper(), self.surname[0].upper(), self.surname[1:])

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Chairman(id=%d, surname=%s)>" % (self.id, self.surname)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если, как показано в примере, `initials` - представляет производное значение из полей модели - не вижу смысла делать для его получения отдельный класс.

Как выше указали - если вам требуется создать свойство, которое будет менять свое "поведение" в зависимости от контекста использования (экземпляр объекта или класс модельки) - то нужно использовать `@hybrid_property` (ну или для метода -  `@hybrid_method`)

Например, ваш пример, если его записать, используя гибридное свойство, будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
class Chairman(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "chairmen"

    id = db.Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    surname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    patronymic = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_property    
    def initials(self):
        return "%s.%s.%s%s" % (self.name[0].upper(), self.patronymic[0].upper(), self.surname[0].upper(), self.surname[1:])  

    @initials.expression   
    def initials(self):
        return func.concat(
                           func.substr(self.name, 0, 1), 
                           func.substr(self.patronymic, 0, 1), 
                           func.substr(self.surname, 0, 1), 
                           func.substr(self.surname, 1, func.length(self.surname))
                           )


    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Chairman(id=%d, surname=%s)>" % (self.id, self.surname)
```

Вторая часть гибридного свойства должна возвращать `sqlalchemy expression` объект.
Что это даст? Вы сможете использовать это короткое свойство в запросах, например можно профильтровать по нему:

```
session.query(Chairman).filter(Chairman.initials=value)
```

И вообще, использовать как обычную колонку в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Хм. Спасибо за ответ, не знал про это. Подождем еще до окончания конкурса, может еще кто-то что-нибудь интересное напишет.

Answer (score 2):

Ничего разделять в данном случае не нужно. У вас есть абстракция (модель), у этой абстракции есть состояние (поля), которое она может хранить (но не обязана). Так же есть методы, через которые можно менять состояние. Еще можно выделить так называемые свойства - по сути те же поля, только вычисляются динамически.

Какой смысл отделять методы и свойства от модели, и делегировать их кому-то еще?

> модели для работы с базой

цель модели работать не с базой данных, а с бизнес-логикой.
Не ассоциируйте модель с базой данных. В общем случае необязательно, чтобы модель хранила свое состояние между перезапусками программы или разными запросами пользователя. Модель это набор полей методов и свойств.

> свойство объекта, который по сути, к БД не относится

объект так же не относится к БД, как и класс этого объекта

насчет `@hybrid_(method/property)` - это просто сахар для выполнения запроса к базе, к вашему вопросу он никакого отношения не имеет. Если вы не собираетесь делать фильтрацию данных в базе по свойству `initials`, то и `@hybrid_property` вам не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Модель, или точнее класс, который представляет собой запись в БД, это объектное представление используемой бд. То есть структура в которой данные и их поведение были объеденены в единое целое, в отличие от той БД, которой вы пользуетесь, для удобства вашей работы с этими данными.

То есть вы можете писать в привычном вам, ну или требуемым кем-то, объектно-ориентированном стиле.

> Вот к примеру у меня класс Chairman - это класс модели из базы данных, а свойство initials - это уже свойство объекта, который по сути, к БД не относится.

Свойство initials, в данном случае, это такое же свойство объекта, как и остальные. Да оно генерируется на основе данных бд, но оно так же является поведением(логикой поведения) вашего объекта. Поэтому вы сделали всё правильно.

Можно даже скрыть все имеющиеся поля, и определить только интерфейс доступа к ним:

```
class Chairman(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "chairmen"

    id = db.Column(INTEGER(unsigned=True), primary_key=True)
    _name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    _surname = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    _patronymic = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

    @property
    def initials(self):  # геттер
        return "%s.%s.%s%s" % (self._name[0].upper(),
                               self._patronymic[0].upper(),
                               self._surname[0].upper(), self._surname[1:])

    def set_data(name, surname, patronymic):  # сеттер
        ...
```

Когда-то смотрел алхимию, помню(очень смутно), что даже можно указывать, чтобы при создании экземпляра модели, всем полям автоматом добавлялся знак подчёркивания.

Ну и, конечно, можно использовать по отношению к модели композицию, агрегацию и другие приёмы объектно-ориентированного проектирования.

Answer (score 0):

Могу сказать, что лучше все свойства и методы класса держать в 1 месте. Разделять имеет смысл в том случае, если у вас может быть обьект класса, который не надо хранить в БД, и поэтому некоторые методы для него должны работать по другому.

Answer (score 0):

Кроме обычных `@property` есть ещё `@hybrid_property`.
Пример из документации:

```
@hybrid_property
def length(self):
    return self.end - self.start
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html